# How to set up Greek Language for Google Assistant SDK on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, google-home, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I have google assistant in a raspberry pi and i want to make an app that will understand my language (Greek), anyone that have an idea on how to make it?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Assistant SDK is currently still in Developer Preview (v1alpha1), and [only supports audio in en-US for now](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha1#encoding). Additional language support is slowly rolling out for the Assistant in general, and as the Assistant SDK matures, it will likely begin tracking those languages eventually. As far as I know, however, Greek was not one of the announced languages at I/O this year, so I don't know when it would be supported.

Comment: yes but i have an idea to connect google translate with google assistant to understand greek (and answer in english). Do you think that will be possible?
thanks